# Change language programmatically

Tags: android

1. How i can change the language in all activities when i chose another language? If i go back to an activity that is previously open it remains with the same configuration. How can refresh that activity too?

i'm using this method:

```
public void setLocale(String lang) {
    Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    Intent refresh = new Intent(this, Language.class);
    startActivity(refresh);
    finish();
}
```

2. How can i save my configurations? If i close the app and open again i want the last configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this solution : 
[Set Locale programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985805/set-locale-programatically)

```
Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preference to store the selected language. And every time you come again on same activity first check on shared preference. like this 
[Language switching inside app android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982715/language-switching-inside-app-android)

I hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
myLocale = new Locale("en");
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

This worked for me. You can change the "en" to a different language is you want. I had the same problem as you did but eventually found this code. Hope it helps you too. Of course you can put this in a button with clicklistener if you want or at start up. This code worked everywhere for me. Good luck.